# Prepare multiple UIFeedbackGenerators

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10, haptic-feedback

To improve the response time of the haptic engine on iPhone7(plus), you have to call `prepare` on the `UIFeedbackGenerator`instance a few seconds before you actually want to perform the feedback.

But what if you want to use a `UIImpactFeedbackGenerator` and `UINotificationFeedbackGenerator`, and want them both to be as responsive as possible?

Will calling `prepare` on the `UIImpactFeedbackGenerator` instance also prepare the `UINotificationFeedbackGenerator` since they are both a subclass of `UIFeedbackGenerator` or do I have to prepare both feedback generators?